# Print blog entry without comments

Tags: printing, blogging

Is there a way to print a blog entry without comments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the piece you want to print, go to: `File` -> `Print` (Or press Ctrl + P) and select the "Selection" radiobutton. (Usually set to "All" by default)

Comment: Thanks, was usinf Safari and didn't see this option, but in Firefox I do.